# Using TinyXML over a byte stream instead of file

Tags: c++, c, tinyxml

Is it possible to use TinyXML over a byte stream instead of a file?

Consider this code snippet:

```
TiXmlDocument doc("abc.xml");
if (!doc.LoadFile())
 return;
TiXmlHandle hDoc(&doc);
```

The above code snippet takes a file as input. How can I modify the code so that it accepts a byte stream? A sample code snippet would be great!

Answer (score 3):

Directly call `TinyXmlDocument::Parse` with the `NULL` terminated byte stream as the first argument. (See the implementation of `TinyXmlDocument::LoadFile` on how to call this function).

Answer (score 1):

After compiling TinyXML with STL support you can use the >> operator defined in the [TiXmlNode](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxmldocs/classTiXmlNode.html) base class:

```
std::istream& operator>> (std::istream & in, TiXmlNode & base)
```

And as a working example:

```
std::istream & stream = /*your stream here*/;
TiXmlDocument xmlDoc;
stream >> xmlDoc;
```

Reference from the TinyXML [documentation](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxmldocs/):

> TinyXML can be compiled to use or not use STL. When using STL, TinyXML uses the std::string class, and fully supports std::istream, std::ostream, operator<<, and operator>>.
>   (...)
>   Use the compile time define: TIXML_USE_STL